# Криптографические библиотеки с поддержкой RSA

Tags: c, linux, g++, c++, gcc

Необходима криптографическая библиотека с поддержкой `RSA` и примерами ее использования. Пытался сделать это с применением `OpenSSL`, но там творилось непойми что и нигде не описанно решение проблем с библеотекой. Библиотека нужна в линукс.

Comment: что такое непойми-что творилось в openssl ? :) может вы лучше опишите проблему в широко используемой библиотеке, чем вот искать что-то скрытое.

Comment: А нужно только RSA? Шифровать сообщение этим алгоритмом -- удовольствие недешовое.

Comment: [man 3 ssl](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/SSL) 

примеры использования: 

 * http://mirror.corbina.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.1p1.tar.gz
 * https://github.com/squadette/mod_ssl

тонны другого софта

Comment: [Crypto++][1]  
Лучше её для плюсов пока ничего нет

  [1]: http://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: RSA настолько прост, что его легко реализовать вручную, потребуется только библиотека длинной арифметики

Comment: @eicto Public Domain (общественное достояние) - куда уж мутнее

Comment: Compilation Copyright (c) 1995-2013 by Wei Dai.  All rights reserved.
This copyright applies only to this software distribution package 
as a compilation, and does not imply a copyright on any particular 
file in the package.

Comment: @eicto из песни слов не выкинешь :-) Вы ведь честно перевели и поняли эту строку _и_ _сам_ _копирайт_ на которую она ссылается?

Comment: @Dith в том и мутность, если compilation copyrated, то это значит использовать ее весьма опасно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The rsa project](http://code.google.com/p/rsa/)

> This is an implementation of the RSA cryptography algorithm.
>
> The project is written in standard C++ from scratch. It currently supports RSA encryption and decryption of files or strings, and RSA key generation. The goal of this project is to make a portable, easy to understand and complete implementation of the RSA algorithm.